# how nagios disable contact_groups?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

In Nogios configurations, I have 2 contacts and 1 contact_group which just include 1 contact, like bellow:

```
define contact{
    contact_name one
}
define contact{
    contact_name two
}
define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name admins
    members    one
}
```

I set my service like this

```
define service {
    name xxx-service
    ...
    contacts two
}
```

when the service trigger, I got two email one is from "one" the other one is from "two".

is there default contact_group or something make this happen? and how can I do to make it just send message to "two"?

Comment: Has your service a `use generic-service` in it?

Comment: @JScoobyCed yes I used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generic-service` in Nagios has this setting in it:

```
define service{
    name                            generic-service
    contact_groups                  admins
    ; ... more stuff
}
```

So emails are sent to the `admins` group (for you it's contact `one`) AND to your `contact two`.

You need to create a new contact group for contact `two` and override the `contact_groups` in your service.

For example:

```
define contact{
    contact_name one
}
define contact{
    contact_name two
}

define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name admins
    members    one
}

define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name helpers
    members    two
}

define service {
    name xxx-service
    ...
    contact_group helpers
}
```

Comment: is that means I can remove the setting ```contacts two``` in ```define service```, and just set the contact_group that include ```two```

Comment: yes, that's it! I added an example based on your settings above